# How to highlight continents in map - google charts

Tags: javascript, charts

I am working on map in which i want to highlight some continents based on some values in map.
Following this example -[https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart](http://google%20geo%20chart)

I want to highlight these four regions on map - APAC (Asia Pacific), NA(North AMerica), Latin America, EMEA(Europe, Middle East and Africa).

Help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple. As far as I know the Google Maps API does not include an option to highlight specific regions that you may want. In order to highlight the areas of the map you'll first need to find a list of coordinates which after drawn acts like a path to create a selection on the map.

**To draw on the Map* follow the Google API guide to draw polygons on the map. This polygon will act as an overlay.

[Drawing on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?csw=1)

[Simple polygon example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple?csw=1)